# How to list posts of a category when the category is clicked using AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

In the homepage there is a menu with some categories and below there are the latest 10 posts.

A post can have many categories and one category can belong to many posts so there are 2 models and a pivot table "category_post" with 2 columns: id and name.

So in the homepage, there is a menu with some categories  and the posts:

```
  <ul class="Categories__Menu"> 
    @foreach($categories->take(6) as $category)
        <li class="ative">
            <a href="" name="category" id="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</a>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>

<div class="row" id="posts">
 @foreach($posts as $post)
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4">
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{$post->image}}" alt="Card image cap">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{$post->name}}</h5>
        <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <a href="{{route('posts.show', ['id' => $post->id, 'slug' => $post->slug])}}" class="btn btn-primary text-white">More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

I want that when each category is clicked to show only the posts of that category in the homepage, but in the same homepage, not in  a specific category page. So maybe the best approach is using AJAX.

Im not understanding what is necessary in the controllers and routes and the jquery is also dont working properly. Do you know how what is necessary to list the posts when a category is clicked with AJAX?

In the **Frontcontroller** I already pass the categories and posts to the homepage view:

```
class FrontController extends Controller
public function index(){
        return view('home')
            ->with('categories', Category::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get())
    ->with('posts', Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(10)->get());

    }
  }
```

**route to the homepage:**

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'FrontController@index',
    'as'   =>'index'
]);
```

**Post and Category models:**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
 }
 class Category extends Model
{
    public function posts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

**In this homepage I have at bottom the ajax below**

```
@section('scripts')
    <script>
$(function() {
    $("a[name='category']").on('click', function(){

        var category_id =$(this).attr("id");
        alert("test");

        $.get('/ajax-category?category_id=' + category_id, function (data) {
            $('#posts').empty();
            $.each(data,function(index, postObj){
                $('#posts').append('');
            });
        });
    });
 });
</script>
@stop
```

**Pivot table "category_post" structure**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('category_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('post_id');
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: There is no `id=category` in your html but you are using that as selector for `$('#category').on('click'...`

Comment: Thanks, I update the question to correct that.

Comment: `'/ajax-category?category_id' + category_id` seems to miss a `=`. Not sure what's that supposed to call from the code you posted though.

Comment: Thanks, I also correct that in the question.

Comment: do you have a model for pivot table ?

Comment: No, I just have a table, I updated the question with the pivot table structure.

Comment: You are giving relative URL in AJAX `'/ajax-category?category_id=' + category_id` so make sure your URL is correct. Also show your controller/model which handle this request

Comment: On click event is not working or AJAX is not working? @jon

Comment: use "change" event in AJAX

Comment: The "alert('test')" dont appears in "$("a[name='category']").on('click', function(){". But also I dont know which route is necessary and if is necessary something on the controller.

Comment: @jon easiest way to do that is you have to create a model for pivot table, otherwise you have to write lot of cording using DB querybuilder, i can post an answer if you like to create a model for pivot table

Comment: Thanks, for me its ok to create a model for the pivot table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in your API route add a new route for your SQL queries, something like this following route :

```
Route::get('posts/where/category/{id}','\Posts@WhereHasCategory')->name('category.posts');
```

Then in your WhereHasCategory function return related posts :

#### API Controller (WhereHasCategory) :

```
public function WhereHasCategory(Request $request)
{
    $posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function ($categories) use (&$request) {
        $categories->where('id',$request->id);
    })->get();

    return response()->json($posts);
}
```

#### Post Model (Many To Many Relationships) :

```
public function Categories () {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'post_category','post_id','category_id');
}
```

You will get those posts that have $request->id category

For your Ajax part, you have to make an ajax request to the above route, You will get the posts which you want, so once you're done change the content of your home page (If you are using VueJS or similar Javascript framework it's really easy) ... That is all, I think!

Try this for your ajax request :

```html
    <a name="category" id="2018" href="#">
        Category
    </a>
    
    <div id="posts">
        <p>Title : Posts Are Here !</p>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("a[name='category']").on('click', function(){
    
                var category_id = $(this).attr("id");
    
                $.ajax({
                    url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
                    type: 'GET',
                    success:function(result){
    
                        $('#posts').empty();
                        $.each(result,function(index, postObj){
                            $('#posts').append("<li>"+postObj.title+"</li><p>"+postObj.body+"</p>");
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        console.log(error.status)
                    }
                });
    
            });
        });
    </script>
```

- Always keep your Javascript queries at the end of the page.

Comment: Thanks. I have the above ajax but not even the "alert("test");" is working. Do you know why?

Comment: Have no idea , It works perfectly in my browser ! Check your JS libraries loading order , Ensure that you have linked them correctly , First you have to load jquery and then your JS scripts by the way always write your scripts at the end of your page

Comment: Now the alert appears but then it appears "Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined".

Comment: @jon Try this one (Edited) .

Comment: Thanks, now it appears on console: "GET http://proj.test/posts/where/category/category_name 500 (Internal Server Error)".

Comment: @jon Check your API , Ensure that everything is working correctly , When you open this link : `proj.test/posts/where/category/category_name` (Change category_name to your category's name , If you want to use ID just change your API function) you have to see JSON output of your function so just return the posts , It's easy and finally just take a look at your `postObj` in your JS queries

Comment: The route is like this: Route::get('posts/where/category/{id}','\Post@WhereHasCategory')->name('category.posts ');

Comment: The method is like this:public function WhereHasCategory(Request $request) {
        $posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function ($categories) use (&$request) {
            $categories->where('id', $request->id);
        });
    }

Comment: The variable $posts is not being used, in the method "WhereHasCategory".

Comment: @jon Just use what i have written , ok `(Answer Edited)` ? I tested it , It works ! :)

Comment: This function "WhereHasCategory" is in the PostController?

Comment: It appears always "jquery.min.js:4 GET http://proj.test/posts/where/category/category_name 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167464/discussion-between-a-o-and-jon).

Answer (score 0):

I think your ajax not working because your page is refreshing when you click the category link, try to add hashtag in the href property.

exsampel:

```
<ul class="Categories__Menu"> 
    @foreach($categories->take(6) as $category)
        <li class="ative">
            <a href="#" name="category" id="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</a>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

or change `<a>` with `<span>`.

sorry for my English. I hope it would help.